# Are there any JSON based notations for Access Control Lists? (Alternative to S-Expression)

Tags: security, json, lisp, protocol, privacy

I'm looking for a notation that is familiar to modern developers and can supersede [s-Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression). (additional insight into [Rivest's proposal of s-Expression is here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Controlling-data-access.html))

Is there any Swagger, JSON or other notation that is very intuitive for ACL control?

Comment: Which ACL notation uses S-expressions?

Comment: @RobertHarvey SPKI and SDSI https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2692 (circa 2004)

Comment: [This was the first match in a Google Search for JSON ACL](https://docs.strongloop.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=3836110).

Comment: The reference you supplied does not mention "ACL" or "Access Control."

Comment: I've been reading about them all night.  I have to find the correct tab, but SDSI and SPKI's merger emphasize "guardian" of PKI-based ACLs in LISP format. I'm just looking for a consumer friendly serialization format for the modern day

Comment: The one I linked to is incredibly clear.  I don't think you're going to get any better than that, unless you're looking for something specific that you have not stated in your question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Would you suggest that JSON is the correct format to express human readable ACLs?

Comment: Why not?  It's used for human-readable/machine readable data of all kinds, it's very concise, it's directly compatible with Javacript, it has extensive software library support... What's not to like?

Comment: Thanks, I'm leaning that way,and perhaps using Protobuf for machine-machine communication.  Will leave this Q up for other considerations... (thank you Robert :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a JSON schema for state machines in the SJOT project:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "$ref": "#/definitions/0",
  "definitions": {
    "0": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "a": { "$ref": "#/definitions/1" },
        "x": { "type": "boolean" }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
"<DEF>": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "a": { "$ref": "#/definitions/<DEF>+1" },
        "b": {
          "anyOf": [
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/0" },
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/<DEF>" }
          ]
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
```

> The JSON Schema has `N` definitions. The "words" we validate with the schema are defined by the regular expression `(a{N}|a(a|b+){0,N-1}b)*x` that describes a sequence of `a` and `b` ending in `x`. The word `abbx` is represented by the JSON pointer `a/b/b/x` which is `{"a":{"b":{"b":{"x":true}}}}`.
>
> Then we add `N-1` definitions `<DEF>` to the schema enumerated `"1", "2", "3", ... "N-1"` where `"<DEF>+1"` wraps back to `"0"` when `<DEF>` is equal to `N-1`.
>
> This `"NFA"` on a two-letter alphabet has `N` states, only one initial and one final state. Its equivalent minimal DFA has `2^N` (2 to the power N) states.
>
> In the worst case, a validator that uses this JSON schema either takes `2^N` time or uses `2^N` memory "cells" to validate the input.

**References**

- [SJOT: Schemas for JSON Objects](https://www.genivia.com/sjot.html)
- [The OTRS Blog - State machines for tickets via ACL - The OTRS Blog](https://blog.otrs.com/2010/08/17/state-machines-for-tickets-via-acl/)
- [JSSCxml Github Repo](https://github.com/Touffy/JSSCxml)
- [Finite State Machine based Access Control (pdf)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2212667813000592/pdf?md5=6956af9257645837388d1b595e3f5bf4&pid=1-s2.0-S2212667813000592-main.pdf&_valck=1)
- [A Finite State Machine Model for Requirements Engineering: How can the standard UML FSM be improved to better serve the… - Requirements Engineering Magazine](https://re-magazine.ireb.org/issues/2015-3-thinking-without-limits/a-finite-state-machine-model/)